# Wrapping content elements causes inline scripts to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I am writing a jQuery plugin. In this plugin I wrap the existing `BODY` contents in a `DIV` and hide them.

```
var $originalBodyContents = $('body').wrapInner('<div>').children('div').hide();
```

The plugin then appends its own overlay `DIV` to the `BODY` and does it's plugin magic. When the user exits the plugin removes its overlay `DIV`, and unwraps them.

```
$originalBodyContents.children().unwrap();
```

This is working great, as you can see in this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vKddB/1/

However, if there are content scripts on the page then they are all reloaded when the wrap occurs and they run their code again. This is causing a lot of unexpected behavior, as you can see in this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vKddB/3/

In the above demo you'll see that the "Show Alert" button shows an alert that says "hello!" when clicked. If you fire the plugin and close the plugin you'll notice that the "Show Alert" button now has two click handlers tied to it so it shows two alerts when clicked.

My plugin will not have control over the contents of the page it is running on. Is there a way I can prevent the inline scripts from re-running when I wrap the body contents in a `DIV`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('script', $('body')).remove();` before your code

Comment: What if the script block contains functions that are being called on that page? I would be removing them from the page. That would be bad. I am only concerned about code that had only expected to run once on initial page load.

Comment: right.. but since the script block is already loaded wouldnt it not make any effect even if its removed? or we can move them to `<head />`

Comment: You sir are correct. Genius I say. I was shocked this worked: http://jsfiddle.net/vKddB/6/

Comment: Lol thanks, I'm still not very great in native javascript though.. Love jQuery

Comment: I took a little video of it in action, thanks @atif089! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGG7ptRKaJs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19550/discussion-between-atif-mohammed-ameenuddin-and-alex-ford)

Comment: At has taken our team a few months to produce what you see in the video. Thanks for the praise :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your plugin to work on arbitrary pages, you might want to consider an alternative approach where your overlay just covers the original contents.  I believe this would be more reliable than tricks such as wrapping and hiding, moving/deleting script nodes, etc.

Comment: I left out details for brevity but the problem is that I cannot used fixed positioning because what our plugin does totally breaks on mobile browsers (It's a report viewer plugin if you were wondering). Absolute positioning works great but the user is able to scroll beyond the overlay and see the underlying body contents. After much trial and error I've come to realize that it is much better if our plugin has the body all to itself while it is open.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my aproach in bulding an overlay maybe it will help someone.
It's a little different, the div is added on the page and does not hide the existing div elements. Maybe a little faster as the script does not search all div dom elements.

first

```
//create the overlay with
$('<div class="overlay" />').appendTo('body').show();

//close the overlay with
$('.overlay').remove();

//css used for overlay
.overlay
{
    background-color: #363636;
    background-image: url('a_nice_bg_image.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: .55;
    filter:alpha(opacity=55);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=55)";
}
```

Comment: This is the approach we originally took, but we ran into tons of issues with `position: fixed` and mobile browsers. That's why we need to hide the original body elements.

Answer (score 0):

Append the div to the body, set its position to absolute, set a high z-index and resize it to cover the whole content.

```
        var $overlay = $('<div>')
        .css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: $(document).width() + 'px',
            height: $(document).height() + 'px',
            backgroundColor: '#f00',
            'z-index': 10000
        })
        .appendTo('body');
```

Like this (your original code with minimal modifications): http://jsfiddle.net/Ya3DG/4/ :)

Comment: The problem with this is if the document is long because of the underlying page content then you get a bunch of blank space in the overlay that the user can scroll through. Our report viewer is supposed to stay within the viewport.