# Wrap a group of elements with children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place the output from a shopping cart app into a bootstrap layout with jQuery.  My html output looks something like this

```
<div id="CWlistings" class="CWcontent">
<h1 class="CWcategoryName">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">
</div>
<div class="CWclear"></div>
```

(from firebug, each div has a child div with its own children.)  I need to wrap either 2 or 3

```
"<div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="">" 's
```

in a div class="row" depending on screen width.  I've tried .wrap() and .wrapAll() about every way I can think of but all I get is errors.
  Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Aren't all those divs missing closing `</div>` tags?

Comment: No, they are there in the code I just copied it out of firebug without opening them for clearity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
while ($('#CWlistings > div.CWlistingBox').length) {
    $('#CWlistings > div.CWlistingBox:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="row" />');
}
```

`:lt(3)` will wrap the divs in groups of three. Use `:lt(2)` to wrap them in groups of two.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8FDP7/)**

The above will produce:

```
<div id="CWlistings" class="CWcontent">
     <h1 class="CWcategoryName"></h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
        <div class="CWlistingBox col-md-4 col-sm-6" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CWclear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a [test](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-while-requery), your code requeries the DOM but it's not slower than caching.

Comment: both j08691 and undefined's answers are excellent and worked great on test pages unfortunatly I seem to have some conflict with other code so I'm still kicking myself,  but thanks for the great answers.  Mike

Comment: I didn't realize at first but some of the divs contained script tags, apparently .wrap has issues with executing scripts.[link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10470)    In my case they were used to write the html elements to the page so I could simply remove them before using the code above like so [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385232/wrapping-content-elements-causes-inline-scripts-to-fire)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method and a simple `for` loop:

```
var $e = $('.CWlistingBox');
for ( var i = 0; i < $e.length; i+=2 ) {
   $e.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="row"/>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure wht do you mean by 2-3 div you need to wrap .. 
you can use $.wrap() for this..

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kHRJA/

```
$('.col-md-4').wrap("<div class='row'>");
```

Comment: He means he needs to wrap the divs together in groups of two or three.